# How to get the part of string that's to the left of a certain pattern in DolphinDB database

Tags: string, dolphindb

A column in a table has the following pattern: XXXX--YY--ZZZZZ. The column has 3 parts separated by --. Each part has variable length.

How to get the first part? I tried function 'split' but it cannot be used on a vector. I also tried each(split, x, "--") but was told not allowed to create String type matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below:

```
t = take("XXXX--YY--ZZZZZ", 10000000)
left(t, strpos(t, "--"))
```

`strpos` returns the position of the specified pattern in a string.